# How to make the second flex item wrap around the first item in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a flex container with two flex items. The first flex item should determine the width of the container, and the second flex item should wrap around it. I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling, but I can't seem to get the desired layout.

Here's my current code:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="flex-initial w-2/3 bg-blue-500 p-4"> <!-- The first child -->
    <!-- Content of the first child -->
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4"> <!-- All the rest components wrap around it -->
    <!-- Content of the rest components -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using w-2/3 to set the width of the first child, but the second child still takes up all the available space in the container. How can I make the second flex item wrap around the first item and have the first item determine the container's width?

Comment: To point of Flexbox is to position elements side-by-side. The flex elements have equal height and cannot wrap around each other. Use your browser's Developer Tools to highlight the flex container so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you mean, but from what I understand you want the second element to be the rest (but not 100% of available space?)

```html
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0 w-2/3 bg-blue-500 p-4">
    <!-- Content of the first child -->
  </div>
  <div class="flex-wrap flex-grow bg-red-500 p-4">
    <!-- Content of the rest components -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you need, would you be able to provide a quick sketch of some sort to make it easier to visualize, and help you further.

Comment: i want to control a width of the parent element with first child, and second child will take the width and wrap text inside it based on the width of the first child

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but here's what I think is the solution:

- First use a fixed width for the first child `div` something like `w-56`
- Then give the parent `div` a `w-fit` class and also the `div` of the rest component

```
<!-- Just a parent div to better visualizethe output -->
<div class="w-screen h-screen p-8 grid  bg-black">
      <div class="w-fit h-fit bg-green-500 flex flex-col">
         parent flex will be also w-56
         <div class=" w-56 bg-blue-500"> <!-- The first child -->
         <!-- Content of the first child -->
           first w-56
         </div>
         <div class="bg-red-500  w-fit"> <!-- All the rest components wrap around it -->
         <!-- Content of the rest components -->
           second
         </div>
      </div> 
</div>
```

Have a look here :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/L59pb6yJAC

Comment: i dont know who voted down. in your example the second element keep grow and expand width of the parent element. I want to parent element width is to be determent by the first element.

Comment: @meha  have you checked the link ? I think it's working as you expected, if you want the second child to take the full width of its parent you can replace `w-fit` with `w-full`